# Cleanup Airflow Database. Xcom Table

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, airflow, devops

What is the best way to clean xcom table in airflow? That's running in docker with postgres db.

I've tried to delete some data with query (Delete from xcom) and try running this reference: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/cleanup-airflow-database  but it doesn't work, xcom table size still doesn't decrease

Related to this case it takes up a lot of storage on my host server

Version I use: Airflow 1.10.3

[image: xcom db]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM xcom WHERE current_date - "timestamp"::date > 14;
```

after execute that query, then run `VACUUM FULL;` from the host

[image: condition after cleanup xcom db]

Answer (score 2):

If you have direct access to the metastore, you could execute this query:

```sql
DELETE FROM xcom;
```

The XCom table contains a timestamp which you can use to preserve recent XComs. For example, this query deletes all XComs older than 14 days:

```sql
DELETE FROM xcom WHERE current_date - "timestamp"::date > 14;
```

If you do not have direct access to the metastore, you could create a DAG to clean up objects in the metastore. Whether you run this on a schedule to clean objects periodically, or without a schedule and run it whenever you want to clean up the database is up to yourself:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.session import provide_session

with DAG(dag_id="cleanup_xcoms", schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)) as dag:

    @provide_session
    def _delete_xcoms(session=None):
        num_rows_deleted = 0

        try:
            num_rows_deleted = session.query(XCom).delete()
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()

        print(f"Deleted {num_rows_deleted} XCom rows")

    delete_xcoms = PythonOperator(task_id="delete_xcoms", python_callable=_delete_xcoms)
```

The XCom object has several attributes which you could filter on, for example `dag_id`:

```py
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == "mydag123").delete()
```

Comment: what if i want to run periodically but with condition like older than 14 days?

Comment: You could set your schedule_interval to "@daily" and add a filter for timestamps older than 14 days, which runs the DAG once a day at midnight and will remove all XComs older than 14 days.